# Mysql resultset grouped and accessible as groups

Tags: php, mysql

I have a result set like so:

```
Name   | Department  |  id
Bill   | Admin       |  1
Tim    | Admin       |  3
John   | Services    |  9
Dave   | Admin       |  2
Martin | Services    |  5
```

I want to get the entire result set but group the results by department.  In my code i want to iterate over each department separately and perform different rendering to each department.

Is it possible in mysql to uniquely identify each group of a result set?

Comment: What about `GROUP BY` in MySQL?

Comment: that is more for aggregation i believe

Comment: I might want order by department, that way all same kind of department will be close

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you:

```
SELECT Departament,GROUP_CONCAT(Name SEPARATOR '-') as Names 
FROM table GROUP BY Departament
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've got it right:

```
select * from T order by Department
```

If you need department list:

```
select distinct Department from T
```